# Lock the sidebar in landscape layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to make my Android application for different devices. I have the sidebar wich is called by the swipe. It is hidden for phone in both orientations and for tablet in portrait. But I want it always to be visible in landscape orientation of tablet, without overlapping the fragment with content.

This is onCreate method of main activity, calle NAvigationActivity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,
        NavigationFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        CatalogFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        NewsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        BlogFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        LessonsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SingleLessonFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

//needed for navigation drawer closing
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private NavigationFragment mNavigationFragment;



/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

private PopupMenu popupMenu;
private Boolean state;
private View menuItemView;
private Menu menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));



    mTitle = getTitle();

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    /**BackStack listener*/
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if (f != null){
                updateTitleAndDrawer (f);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

And this is code of the sidebar called NavigationDrawerFragment

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_catalog),
                    getString(R.string.title_news),
                    getString(R.string.title_blog),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
/**Needed for GLOBAL menu */
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.        See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {

        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}

public ListView getmDrawerListView() {
    return mDrawerListView;
}
}
```

If you have any ideas, please share with me. If I should insert more code, or delete some, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one helps out

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
```